# Trouble updating pgfplots on Windows/MikTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, miktex, installing, updating

I'm trying to update to a newer version of pgfplots, preferably v1.12. I'm currently using v1.7.

First, I opened `Update` (admin mode) with MikTeX and it didn't have any updates for pgfplots. Then I downloaded the folder from CTAN for v1.12 and followed the instructions in the manual: opened `Settings` (admin mode), went to `Root`, added unzipped folder, moved it to the top (it was the only thing listed), applied.

`\pgfplotsversion` still listed 1.7.

Then opened the `Package Manager` (admin mode), changed repositories, synced, installed pgfplots and pgf (both listed as being updated in 2014).

`\pgfplotsversion` STILL lists 1.7 being used.

What else can I try or what am I doing wrong?

Edit: When I check the "Show MikTeX-maintained root directories" box, I see two other things. Is it a problem that I can't move my option up before one of them? See picture.

[image]

Comment: Try checking for updates in the non-admin Updates area. Depending on how/where the package was originally installed, it may show up here instead.

Comment: Did you download `pgfplots.**tds**.zip`. You should create a LocalTeXMF directory, register it via `MiKTeX Options`, and unzip the file there, and finally refresh the FNDB.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks @PaulGessler! The non-admin Update found some stuff to update/remove(?), and after updating it now prints out 1.12. =)

http://i.imgur.com/HpyA4hL.png <- screenshot of updates found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the package was originally installed "on-the-fly" or by using the user-mode Package Manager, its updates will appear only in the user-mode Update tool.

Only packages installed using the admin-mode Package Manager will appear in the admin-mode Update tool. I've now switched to TeX Live, but back in my MikTeX days I would always be sure to check for updates using both tools to get all possible new versions.

Comment: If this is a dupe of a more general question, feel free to vote as such. I searched for one but couldn't find anything.